# Magento 2 : search into category name

Tags: magento2, search, toolbar

When a user is making a search on my website I would like to search into categories name, for example if the user is searching for "house" I would like to display all products containing "house" in their name (default behavior) but also all products of categories containing "house" in their name.

I wrote the code below, it's working great I have all products but the toolbar is not working anymore (order, limit, pager...).Is there any way to "reload" the toolbar with my new collection?

Thanks !

> File: di.xml

```
<!-- Set plugin -->
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search\CollectionFilter">
    <plugin name="CategoryName_Search" type="My\Module\Model\Layer\Search\Plugin\CollectionFilter" />
</type>
```

> File: My\Module\Model\Layer\Search\Plugin\CollectionFilter

```
public function afterFilter(
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search\CollectionFilter $subject,
$result,
$collection,
Category $category
) {
$query = $this->queryFactory->get();

if (!$query->isQueryTextShort()) {
    //Get categories list by name
    $categoryCollection = $this->collectionFactory
      ->create()
      ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$query->getQueryText().'%'));

    //For each product in these categories add product to search collection
    foreach($categoryCollection as $category) {
      $categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

      foreach($categoryProducts as $product) {
        if (!$collection->getItemById($product->getId())) {
          $collection->addItem($product);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: does anyone have an idea how to fix this ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: did you find any solution for that ?